# Github Action trigger with path and on working directory

Tags: github-actions

I have the following github action :

```
on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - 'path1/**'
      - 'path2/**'
  jobs:
    example:
       name: "example"
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    defaults:
     run:
       working-directory: ./path/to/my/working_directory
```

I am trying to trigger the flow only when a file is pushed on the following directories

- 'path1/**'
- 'path2/**'

but it seems that the flow is triggered every time even if i push something in other directories (ex. path3/**).

Could it be because of the working-directory  because path1 and path2 are in the root directory.

Any ideas will be appreciated it.

Comment: How it doesn't work correctly ? What is not working as you expect it to work ?

Comment: The workflow is triggered every time , i expect to be triggered when i change something in the folders list

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to update the question and provide an abstract example on what i wanna do. Please tell me if still is not clear and i ll clarify it even more.

Comment: Can you provide the directory structure where this is being run?